# How to add a scope to an app on Paypal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm developping an app on Paypal and i'm rather new to the environnement
I've been following this documentation to create Disputes on a sandbox account :
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/disputes/integration-guide/
I've been struggling with the first step :
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/disputes/integration-guide/#link-setupbuyersidecredentialstocreateadisputeinthesandbox
I am going crazy i can't find anything in the documentation of Paypal that tells me HOW to setup the scopes :

> Set up your REST app with the following scope:
> **https://uri.paypal.com/services/disputes/create = DISPUTE_CREATE**

for the app and allow me to procede with my testing

I searched all over Paypal's documentation and i found nothing
I'm asking for a little bit of help if anyone knows how to setup scopes for an app on paypal
I'd be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set scopes by adjusting permissions in [the application settings](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications), which do not include anything that maps to this dispute creation scope. Contact PayPal for support.